# Typo in empty tag wiki pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, character-escaping

Go to any empty tag wiki page (like [this one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/codeigniter-classloader/info), or [this one on SU](https://superuser.com/tags/effective-permissions/info), or [this one on SF](https://serverfault.com/tags/alliedware/info)) and read the first sentence:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag u2026 yet!

…looks like someone forgot to escape their [horizontal ellipsis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm).

This bug seems to occur network-wide.

Comment: Eeeek! More of these!!??

Comment: @Cole yeah, they're oscillating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunate timing there, there's actually been a fix sitting for a couple hours but I didn't realize we'd built out the bug.

A fix is going out with the newest build, which is in rolling out at time of writing.